# Why is linux boot sequence in sh and not in c

Tags: linux, boot, speed

I have an embedded device which runs linux.

I'm trying to speed up the boot sequence. Would rewriting large parts of the boot sequence in C speed up a lot?

for example I have a lot of scripts which test for this or that, then mount this or that. This is /etc/rcS.d/S03sysfs

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -e /proc ] && ! [ -e /proc/mounts ]; then
  mount -t proc proc /proc
fi

if [ -e /sys ] && grep -q sysfs /proc/filesystems; then
  mount sysfs /sys -t sysfs
fi

exit 0
```

My guess is that if it was in C, it would be much faster right?

My questions :

Why isn't it already in C?
Would there be a speed gain to write this in C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be *somewhat* faster in C, but the language choice isn't what affects performance the most. It is usually more effective to perform various tasks in parallel, rather than waiting for each to complete sequentially as simpler init systems do. For example, *sshd* and *httpd* could be started at the same time, since neither requires the other to be already running.

---

There is no single "Linux boot sequence". Each distribution has its own; there isn't even a single thing they all have in common. It *can* be in C, Perl, Haskell, anything; the only requirement is that an executable named `/init` be present in the initramfs, or `/sbin/init` in the root filesystem.

The `/etc/rc?.d` scheme is simply an extension of the Unix boot process of 20 years ago, maybe even 30 years. The earliest Unix systems were rebooted fairly rarely, so they would have a simple script, `/etc/rc` or similar, that would be launched by *init* and start various daemons sequentially.

Even today *SysV init* is being used to start all such scripts, although the exact method may vary. Originally, a system would start all scripts in `/etc/rc?.d` in order; currently Debian uses Makefile-style dependencies.

Some distributions – Ubuntu, Chrome OS, Fedora up to v14 – have switched to [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), which is written in C and is "event-based", allowing daemons to be started in parallel. Another init system, [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd), appears to be rising quickly in popularity – it is used by default in Fedora and OpenSuSE. It is also written in C. (Both systems still read textual configuration files to decide which daemons are to be started.)

[image]

Those distributions which still stick with SysVinit usually do it for "simplicity"; the most commonly heard <sup>[citation needed]</sup> arguments appear to be about shell scripts being easier to maintain than equivalent C code (although said shell scripts consist of 90% copypasta), as well as a mortal fear of introducing additional library dependencies <sup>[subjective]</sup>. You can see for yourself in [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.general/170648), [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.general/170802), [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.general/171344) and [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.general/171695) discussion threads on the Debian mailing list from May 2012.

(Disclaimer: I'm a *systemd* user myself.)

Comment: [This](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink) is also an interesing read as well as: [Why shouldn't we use the word 'here' in a textlink](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink)

Comment: I have only a single core on my device so parallel stuff will not boost speed very much would it? Unless my startup blocks a lot... does it?

Comment: @user1190: Waiting on IO is a common block, so even on a single core you should see gains.

Answer (score 5):

> Why isn't it already in C?

For cross-platform compatibility and because it allows to use sh files to describe the boot process. Maintaining boot scripts in C would be a PITA.

> Would there be a speed gain to write this in C?

Not much. While some parts would be faster, the overall speed gain would be marginal. Most of the boot process is strictly sequential, specially the steps in init 1 and 2. From init 3 and upward, the boot processes could be paralellized using something like [Runit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Runit), which would get you big speed gains.

Comment: The boot scripts do not have to be 100% C code; they could still read textual configuration files (such as `fstab` for filesystems), [for example, this](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/samba/trunk/smbd.service).

Comment: Stil a hassle to maintain. As a Debian package maintainer, it's easier to maintain SH files than C files. Using a C boot script would introduce GCC as a dependency.

Comment: Why would GCC be a dependency for a program that can be distributed as a binary package? Remember that sysvinit is also written in C. (Also, as a maintainer of several Arch packages, I've found it *much easier* to ensure the consistency of 5-line unit files which work everywhere, than 20-line shell scripts which vary from distro to distro.)

Comment: I meant Build-Dependency. Still, boot scripts are maintained and modified by package maintainers. It's the same argument of why one would prefer to do a perl script or a c program for a sysadmin task. Most people would choose a scripting language than a compiled one for such a task.

Comment: The init system itself already is written in C and has the compiler as Build-Dep. On the other hand, the initscripts for each service do not have to be scripts at all; they can be simple *textual* configuration files, as in my earlier example. There is no reason for them to be compiled.

Comment: @grawity: We could call the text files "scripts" and the C code "the shell" and then -- oh wait, that's how it's set up now.  Seriously, what sort of speed up do you think you might get?  Bear in mind that the shell will already be read into RAM, the other reasons for keeping it that are mentioned on this page, and the very small performance gain with lots of admin pain...

Comment: One difference is that `sh` scripts rely on a large number of external programs; even if they are cached in memory, fork()ing them still has a cost larger than that of a single mount() syscall (as in the OP's example). As for admin pain, the only change I've seen so far is *decrease*. (I feel that I'm getting involved in a third flamewar this week. I should stop.)

Answer (score 2):

Most of what it spends its time doing is waiting for things, one after the other: filesystems, networks, etc.

If you want a *really* fast boot sequence, boot with init=/bin/sh - instant command prompt! If it's an embedded system, you could have it boot straight into your application.